# xpath - get element by text considering inner elements

Tags: xpath, automated-tests

When I have an HTML similar to this:

```
<button>text</button>
```

this xpath retrives me the correct element: `.//button[normalize-space()="text"]`

but when I have an HTML similar to this:

```
<button>
<span class="foo">text</span>
<span class="bar"></span>
</button>
```

the same xpath does not work, how do I build an xpath considering that textContent may sometimes be inside innerelements?

Comment: The same xpath  `.//button[normalize-space()="text"]` or `.//button[normalize-space(.)="text"]` should work, even if the text is associated to child node.

Comment: The above @supputuri comment is correct. Unless there is some content you haven't show to us like `&nbsp;`...

Answer (score 0):

Actually your expression should match both buttons so you don't need to amend it

[image]

---

Just in case you can use [`|` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) to combine 2 XPath expressions evaluation results like:

```
//button[normalize-space()="text"] | //button/child::*[normalize-space()="text"]
```

References:

- [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=21986281)
- [Xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)